# Maximum concurrent calls to WCF service

Tags: wcf, iis, concurrency

We have a wcf service hosted in IIS (Win 2012). We expect thousands of messages coming throughout the day, however the peak would be around 4K concurrent messages. All these are one way (async) requests and wcf service performs some processing which will take several seconds for each request.
 - Is there any limitations on max concurrent requests that can be sent to wcf svc hosted on IIS? Does it depend on thread availability on server? Any settings that needs tweaking would be useful.

In another scenario, we have less number of async requests coming to wcf svc, however for each request service performs few things parallely (Parallel.ForEach). What would be maximum parallel threads available in this scenario and does it depend on any other factors? Any settings that needs tweaking would be useful.

Comment: One way != async. One way calls still return. Async calls do not

Comment: Is your service receiving requests over the internet? Or intranet only?

Comment: It receives requests only from intranet